# Редактирование в массиве json

Tags: массивы, json

Добрый вечер!

Возможно это пустяк, но не получается его сделать!

В общем есть информация в БД, в формате json.

В нем МАРКИ машин, а в внутри каждой марки - по 2-4 модели!

Эту инфу я достаю через json_decode.

И через цикл "foreach ($massiv['models'] as $model):" вытаскиваю в таблицу "CARS".

Новые модели я добавляю, а вот как удалять и редактировать модели!

1) Как сделать unset, если id модели динамический?!

Вот как удалить из "БМВ" первую модель "М3", чтобы 2 оставшиеся сдвинулись вверх и номер 2 стал номером 1. а номер 3 стал 2?!

2) Как редактировать модели, если id модели опять же динамический?

Как можно к примеру в третьей модели "БМВ Х6", поменять название модели, описание и имя фото?

Заранее спасибо за помощь новичку!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если у вас 5.7 то можно так https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html

Comment: а насколько вообще правильно хранить `json` в БД. 1 - НФ или нет? Может если смысл распарсить его сначала, если такие частые особенно...

Comment: 1) Версия php до 5.2;  2) json в БД надо хранить - учеба у меня такая! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой правильный ответ:

Надо было просто указать цикл

```
foreach ($massiv['models'] as $key=>$model):
```

, где `$key` - и есть нужный мне динамичный ключ!

Comment: Странно! Как может быть правильный ответ НЕ ПОЛЕЗНЫМ???!  Кто додумался до такого?! И тогда какой же ответ является по мнению этого умника ПОЛЕЗНЫМ???